# Getting the number of concurrent requests for each bin in Kusto / Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to know how many requests are *currently* executing at any given second in Azure Application Insights.

For example, if request 1 starts at 10:00:00 and finished at 10:00:03 (timestamp of 10:00:00 and duration of 3999ms), it should be counted in the rows for 10:00:00, 10:00:01, 10:00:02 and 10:00:03

The output should be something like:

```
| timestamp               | count_ |
| ----------------------- | ------ |
| 0000-00-00T00:00:00.000 | 254    |
| 0000-00-00T00:00:00.001 | 345    |
| 0000-00-00T00:00:00.002 | 216    |
```

I thought I could maybe use the `join` operator against a table of seconds, but I cannot use something like `on $right.timestamp >= $left.timestamp and $right.timestamp + duration < $left.timestamp`, kusto replies with `join: Only equality is allowed in this context.`.

So how can I get concurrent requests (or dependencies) by timestamp bin?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you can tell the start and end of each session, you can use the [range()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/rangefunction) function to generate the applicable datetime values by the bin size when the session is active, and then use the [mv-expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator) operator to expand the list so you can count the concurrent sessions. Here is an example:

```
let sampleEvents = datatable(sessionId:string,eventType:string, timestamp:datetime)
["A", "start", datetime(2020-02-29T10:32:52.1953143Z),
"A", "end", datetime(2020-02-29T10:33:08.1953143Z),
"B", "start", datetime(2020-02-29T10:32:57.1953143Z),
"B", "end", datetime(2020-02-29T10:33:10.1953143Z)];
let startEvents = sampleEvents | where eventType =="start" | project startTime = timestamp, sessionId;
startEvents
| lookup kind=leftouter (sampleEvents | where eventType =="end" | project endTime=timestamp, sessionId) on sessionId
| extend endTime = iif(isempty(endTime), now(), endTime)
| extend sessionActiveTimeInOneSecondInterval = range(startTime, endTime, 1s)
| mv-expand sessionActiveTimeInOneSecondInterval to typeof(datetime)
| summarize count() by bin(sessionActiveTimeInOneSecondInterval, 1s)
```

Also consider using the [row_window_session()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/row-window-session-function) function to determine the session's start time

Comment: I know about bin, but as far as I know any given entry can only be present once by bin, and using workarounds by creating bins first earlier and then joining doesn't work because I need to write a range condition on each join and I don't know how, hence this post.

Comment: Sorry Christian I did not read it carefully, I updated my answer, hopefully this works for you.